# Absolutely bogus tag info edit reject

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11694952 (still pending) *(update: approved! thank you to all who voted)*.

One of the reviewers voted to reject. The reason given:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

The edit is written by one of well known experts in the field, and is the first edit on a previously empty tag info page.

I'm at a loss. Maybe this was an accident? But the reviewer has an unusual (to me) heavy  history of rejections of edits.

What is usually done in such cases?

Comment: I approved it and asked others to have a look at it as well

Comment: Why does that entire block of text not even mention the word "non-termination" anywhere?

Comment: "termination" is discussed.

Comment: I see that, but the tag is non-termination, and when reading a tag wiki about it, I would expect to find information about what **non**-termination means. This wiki kinda makes it seem like the tag name should just be termination. It's rather confusing to anyone who is not an expert in Prolog. What's so special about non-termination that "lack of" termination couldn't just be explained in a termination tag wiki?

Comment: "non-X" means the lack of X.

Comment: Whatever the answer, enough reviewers choose the correct action by now. The review is complete. The loss of value is prevented.

Comment: maybe these two tags indeed should be merged...

Comment: Looks like a standard robo-reviewing accident, he reviewed ~130 posts in 40 minutes.  Yikes.

Comment: @WillNess : I added the line `Non-termination is the lack of termination.` at the end of your Wiki. Even though that may be obvious to most of us, at least now it explicitly mentions non-termination. ;-)